# How to show surfaceview that play video in circular shape? Android

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-videoview

I want play a video in circular surface view in android but can't achieve this. Can anyone help me about this?

Comment: <FrameLayout><SurfaceView/><View background="circle_background"/></FrameLAyout>

Comment: I don't think so it works.

Comment: why not? any reason?

Comment: Setting a circular background mask on the SurfaceView's View, leaving the interior transparent to let the Surface show through, should be exactly what you need.

Comment: Can you give me some sample code?